# Proof that $A \times C\subseteq B \times C \iff A \subseteq B$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I am currently learning proofs, and I am not sure if my proof is correct, can someone please verify?

Proof:
First we prove that  $A \times C \subseteq B \times C \implies A \subseteq B$ by a contrapositive proof.

Assume that $A \nsubseteq B$, then $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $a \notin B$. Since $C \subseteq C$, $c \in C$ but $a \notin B$, we have that $(a,c) \in A \times C$ and $(a,c) \nsubseteq B \times C$, this implies that $A \times C \nsubseteq B \times C$.

Now we prove that  $ A \subseteq B \implies A \times C \subseteq B \times C $ by a direct proof.

Since $A \subseteq B$, $\forall a \in A, a \in B$. Since $C \subseteq C$,
$\forall (a,c) \in A \times C$, $(a,c) \in B \times C$, thus $A \times C \subseteq B \times C$.

Edit: Assume that A, B and C are nonempty sets.

Comment: The only fault is that you assumed $c\in C$. Why can you do that when $C$ may be empty?

Comment: @Trebor, you are right, thank you.

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty; only when $C$ is nonempty is the statement false.

Comment: It's true with $A$ and/or $B$ is empty.  You will need to prove those cases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are an alternative for one of the implications, which is more direct and shows that only $C$ must be non-empty.

- $(\Longrightarrow)$ We have $A \times C \subseteq B \times C$.
  Since $C$ is assumed to be non-empty there is an element $c \in C$.
  Now let $x \in A$, then $(x, c) \in A \times C$ and by the assumption we get $(x, c) \in B \times C$ and therefore also $x \in B$.